# What is the most common format to show a meaningful message to the user when an error occurs - Swift

Tags: swift, error-handling

What is the most common way to show a meaningful message to the user when an error occurs?

I'm using CoreLocation to determine the users location and I'm trying to handle errors as best as possible.

I have the following code which shows an Alert message if an error occurs.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)-> Void in
        /// Show ERROR
        if error != nil {               
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription.description, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { action in
                /// stop updating
                self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                return
            }))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        if placemarks!.count > 0 {
            // do stuff here with the found placemark
        }else{
            print("No placemarks found.")
        }
    })
}
```

For instance if there is no internet connection the user will see the following error...

> > Error: 
> >     The operation could't be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 2.)

Is this how you would normally present an error to the user or you would instead replace the error message with some generic message like... "Sorry but we couldn't connect to the server. Make sure you are connected to the internet"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the error messages should be something that the user can easily understand.

Errors like this

```
Error: The operation could't be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 2.)
```

are usually for the developers understanding as to why this error is occurring. It's given by the compiler and is not suitable to present this to the user as it is. So for a real time app, it is better to use generic messages for all error messages & also success messages.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I know it was a silly question but this is the first time I deal with connections to third party services (HTTP requests).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a `UIAlertController` is probably the most standard way to present an error to the user unless you want to get fancy and put the effort in to make your own customized error subview.

[One of the 10 heuristics of UI design states that:](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/)

> Error messages should be expressed in plain language (no codes), precisely indicate the problem, and constructively suggest a solution.

So, I would suggest writing your own error code for this instance such as `"There was an error updating your location"` instead of using `error.localizedDescription.description`. This will improve the usability of your application for its users.

Comment: I wasn't concerned about the `UI` for presenting the message, I was more interested on the error message itself.